# Grouping Results - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How do I solve this problem ?

I have table that contains Training Versions , the last version and the currently version , both are on same row.

What do i want ?

Find way to create an ID to reference each other grouping by course .

Show the situation bellow :

[image]

And I want to get that result bellow :

[image]

can  someone help me out ?

I have to ensure that the latest version is the current version.

**I'm working on SQL SERVER 2014.**
Thanks !

Comment: select ..1 .. 1  ..1 UNION select ..2 ..2 ..2

Comment: Please don't post images. Post text which other can copyto the answer to help you.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the grouping numbers? is it just by first word in `Name Training` or ….

Comment: @lUUK I GOT GROUPING NUMBER BY id ! Imagine i have variable(ID) and this variable have to looking in the table and get currently ID and the last ID by course. Remember . The first picture i have  ACTUAL and Earlier courses .  It's complicate to explain

Comment: It impossible, with current info, to get the correct value for `IdGroup`. That piece is also missing from the answer [MJH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9395740/mjh) gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT [V1 columns]
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [V2 columns]
FROM MyTable;
```

That will append the results together, if you want to eliminate duplicates, you can use:

```
SELECT [V1 columns]
FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT [V2 columns]
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Good but how do i get last version of the course that im looking for ? 
Might be rank solve this ?

Comment: Thanks man you solved my problem hahaha . Its impossible to find the last version without the column which refferes that COURSE is the last course of the line. Looking at this pictures that ive posted , the only way to find is using RANK function on version training right ?